# create implicit data without having to create temp/volatile/working table

Tags: sql, teradata

This is possible:

```
SELECT 'Bla' AS X
```

why is this not possible in TeraData:

```
SELECT 'Bla' AS X
        UNION  
SELECT 'DiBla' AS X
```

Is there a way to achieve the above without having to create a temp/volatile/working table in TeraData?

PS:

The error is: A select for a union, intersect or minus must reference a table

Answer (score 0):

If you want two columns on one row, then use:

```
SELECT 'Bla' AS X, 'DiBla' AS Y
```

If you want:

```
X
Bla
DiBla
```

Then you just do:

```
select 'Bla' as X
union all
select 'DiBlah' as X;
```

If you want:

```
X       Y
Bla     NULL
NULL    DiBla
```

Then:

```
SELECT 'Bla' as X, NULL as Y
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as X, 'DiBla' as Y
```

Comment: Thanks but I want one column called X.

Comment: I guess I could use the above and then use coalesce but seems very cumbersome

Comment: @cs0815 . . . Then why do you call one column `Y` in the question.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake one column was called X and the other X. Both are now called X.

Answer (score 0):

You have a attribute name mishmash in your `UNION`. You can not perform `UNION` between relations having different structure. Therefore, use

```
SELECT cast('Bla' as varchar(6)) AS X FROM (SELECT 1 a) t
    UNION  
SELECT cast('DiBla' as varchar(6)) AS X  FROM (SELECT 1 a) t
```

the explicit casting make sure that the data types are equivalent as well as the attribute names. Another solution could be

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT cast('Bla' as varchar(6)) AS X
) t
UNION  
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT cast('DiBla' as varchar(6)) AS X
) t
```

Comment: @cs0815 and if you add the artificial table like in the example?

Comment: @cs0815: What's your Teradata release? This should work as-is.

Comment: It is quite old so that's probably the reason )-: